# Installing the Android environment

Tags: android, installation

Is there any different method to install the android environment on Eclipse other than the same methods described in all sites like this one 
http://android-pour-les-nuls.fr/tutoriaux/developpement/307-tutoriel-installation-de-lenvironnement-de-developpement-eclipse-android

Comment: Stick to the official guide: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eclipse marketplace to download android sdk manager

Comment: thx a lot, I am still needing another method, I must quote three, I just named two.

Answer (score 1):

There you got everything required. Now, almost everything is in Eclipse: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

For future development, remember always to check first http://developer.android.com